# ConnectionString password - XML escaping

Tags: c#, xml

I have a strong password that I am having some trouble to put it on my web.config:

So my web.config entry is:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx;Password=MyPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And my strong password is:

> <=#}U}2{p^07>7u10)'*g7|5=96!;a1F2="=!,}7;65\3{9P0w(#/]${06|S
>   /L2=l{0[2E32+78AJ|@;9}$N=|(0s9,=\N|o+t

So the issue is related with some character that need to be escaped, but I tried with no success to escape it using single quotes.

Thanks

Comment: Now that everyone knows your strong password, you might as well change it for compatibility with XML attribute syntax :-)

Comment: Actually it's not my password, it's similar, but I challenge you to do something with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried with no success to escape it using single quotes

What that doesn't actually escape anything - it just allows you to have a double-quote as part of your value. But then it means you can't have an apostrophe as part of your value... it's probably simpler to turn *both* into entity representations... along with `<` and `&`.

So in this case you want:

```
&lt;=#}U}2{p^07>7u10)&apos;*g7|5=96!;a1F2=&quot;=!,}7;65\3{9P0w(#/]${06|S /L2=l{0[2E32+78AJ|@;9}$N=|(0s9,=\N|o+t
```

If you had an `&` in your original password, you'd convert that to `&amp;`.

Or for more simplicity, when you're generating a password, force it to *not* have any characters that will require escaping. (Or move to a different authentication model, of course...)

Or come up with this programmatically, as per PetSerAl's answer, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Allow system to handle this for you:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    new XElement("add",
        new XAttribute("name","MyConnectionString"),
        new XAttribute("connectionString",
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder {
                DataSource="tcp:xxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433",
                InitialCatalog="MyDatabase",
                MultipleActiveResultSets=true,
                UserID="xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx",
                Password=Console.ReadLine()
            }
        ),
        new XAttribute("providerName","System.Data.SqlClient")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744153/connectionstring-password-xml-escaping/28744498#28744498) that you should just use a high-level API to create your XML for you.  But if you must format your XML text manually, the [`SecurityElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has utilities to escape and unescape XML text:

```
        string password = @"<=#}U}2{p^07>7u10)'*g7|5=96!;a1F2=""=!,}7;65\3{9P0w(#/]${06|S /L2=l{0[2E32+78AJ|@;9}$N=|(0s9,=\N|o+t";

        var xmlText = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(password); // Escape invalid XML characrers.

        var passwordBack = new System.Security.SecurityElement("tag", xmlText).Text;  // Unescape them again.

        Debug.Assert(passwordBack == password); // No assert
```